# Can I upload a Word document and turn it into a form?

Tags: cognito-forms

Is it possible to upload a Word document and turn it into a form?

I have a new employee questionnaire that I would like to use instead of doing it from scratch.

Comment: You forget to off caps key.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

We do not offer a way to import or convert a Word document into a Cognito Form. You will have to build your form in Cognito based on your Word document.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your help, still a great and valuable tool you have.

Answer (score 0):

I would either upload it to something like hellosign (depending on your needs) or save it as a PDF and add form fields in Adobe Acrobat.